# how to get the special url from a page?

Tags: python, css-selectors

I want to get addresses from urls like this `http://openinnovation.cn/node/****` from [this page](http://openinnovation.cn/opentools/function/58):

Here a snippet:

```
<div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even"> 
    <span class="views-field views-field-title"> 
        <span class="field-content">
            <a href="http://simile.mit.edu/wiki/Babel" target="_blank">babel</a>
        </span>
    </span>  
    <span class="views-field views-field-nothing"> 
        <span class="field-content"><a href="http://openinnovation.cn/node/9506">详细信息</a>
        </span> 
    </span>
</div>
```

What I want is this string "http://openinnovation.cn/node/9506"

I have tried several methods but all failed, this in one of them. I am a newbie, and only know how to select classes, ids, and others I leaned from codecademy.

```
infoURL = page_html.cssselect(".views-field views-field-nothing, .field-content, a.attrib['href']")
```

Here is the related function:

```
def main():
    for j in range(58,64):
        listURL = 'http://www.openinnovation.cn/opentools/function/'+str(j)
        listPage = urllib.urlopen(listURL)
        listhtml = listPage.read()
        page_html = lxml.html.fromstring(listhtml)
        # get the information page url from the list page:
        #infoURL = page_html.cssselect("a.ttrib['href']")

        infoURL = page_html.cssselect(".views-field views-field-nothing, .field-content, a.attrib['href']")
        for e in infoURL:
            print e
```

Thanks very much!

Comment: You tagged the question with python but did not provide code which suggests that you already tried something. Please provide code by editing your question. Also, how specific or general do you want the selector to be?

Comment: To get all the urls like http://openinnovation.cn/node/**** in the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how specific you want to select the node you can either use

```
.views-row > span:nth-of-type(2) a
```

to select the link in the second span or

```
a[href*='//openinnovation.cn/node/']
```

to select all the links that contains a specific string in its `href` attribute. This uses the `attribute*='string'` attribute selector which you can read more about [here](http://css-tricks.com/attribute-selectors/). CSS is not as powerful as XPath so you cannot select the `href` attribute directly. You will have to explicitly get the attribute from `e` using the lxml API:

```
infoURLs = page_html.cssselect("a[href*='//openinnovation.cn/node/']")
for urlNode in infoURLs:
    print urlNode.get("href")
```